# Merge/update json objects from two different json files

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have two JSON files, both have the same number of objects and each object has an ID key `"DOCN"`, the problem is some objects have different keys, for example in file1 the object `"DOCN": "000093019"` has 4 keys, while in file2 the same object has 5 ..

I'm trying to create a new file that contains the same objects in both files (find the missing ones in file1 and file2 and add them to the object)

Example:

file1:

```
[
    {
        "DOCN": "000093019",
        "A": "blabla",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla"
    },
    {
        "DOCN": "000093085",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla",
        "D": "blabla"
    }
]
```

file2:

```
[
    {
        "DOCN": "000093019",
        "A": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla",
        "D": "blabla",
        "E": "blabla"
    },
    {
        "DOCN": "000093085",
        "A": "blabla",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla"
    }
]
```

what I would like to achieve:
file3:

```
[
    {
        "DOCN": "000093019",
        "A": "blabla",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla",
        "D": "blabla",
        "E": "blabla"
    },
    {
        "DOCN": "000093085",
        "A": "blabla",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla",
        "D": "blabla"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is a simple manipulation on the dictionaries. I cannot say this will be best performing for a large dataset. But you can merge the dicts based on the key "DOCN". (May be there are better appraoches! ;-))

```
f1 = [
    {
        "DOCN": "000093019",
        "A": "blabla",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla"
    },
    {
        "DOCN": "000093085",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla",
        "D": "blabla"
    }
]

f2 = [
    {
        "DOCN": "000093019",
        "A": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla",
        "D": "blabla",
        "E": "blabla"
    },
    {
        "DOCN": "000093085",
        "A": "blabla",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla"
    }
]

f1 = {item.get("DOCN"): item for item in f1}
f2 = {item.get("DOCN"): item for item in f2}

keys = set(list(f1.keys())+list(f2.keys()))

output = []
for key in keys:
    output.append({**f1.get(key), **f2.get(key)})

print(output)
```

The output was:

```
[
    {
        "DOCN": "000093019",
        "A": "blabla",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla",
        "D": "blabla",
        "E": "blabla"
    },
    {
        "DOCN": "000093085",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla",
        "D": "blabla",
        "A": "blabla"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would read both of them in two different arrays and map it to create new one.

````
// read file1 instead using `fs`
const arr1 = [
    {
        "DOCN": "000093019",
        "A": "blabla",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla"
    },
    {
        "DOCN": "000093085",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla",
        "D": "blabla"
    }
]
// read file2 instead
const arr2 = [
    {
        "DOCN": "000093019",
        "A": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla",
        "D": "blabla",
        "E": "blabla"
    },
    {
        "DOCN": "000093085",
        "A": "blabla",
        "B": "blabla",
        "C": "blabla"
    }
]

const arr3 = arr1.map(
    x => {
      const val = arr2.find(y => y.DOCN === x.DOCN)
      x= {
        ...x,
        ...val
      }
      return x
    })

//write arr3 to new file
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the following way - load 2 files using pandas, concat dataframes, group by `DOCN` and take the first record (this will take the none None values) and then turn it into a list and remove None entries -

```
df1 = pd.read_json("my_file1.json")
df2 = pd.read_json("my_file2.json")
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
grp = df.groupby("DOCN").first().reset_index()
[{k: v for k, v in record if v} for record in grp.to_dict(orient='records')]
```

Comment: Very interesting approach, however, it won't work in my case since some of the keys in both files have the value `None`.